# XML-file cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the problem that my java-file does not seem to recognice my XML-file and I don't know why. Can someone please explain why it doesn't work. In the Java-file below R.layout.fragment_1 cannot be resolved or is not a field:

```
package com.example.transitioningfragments;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false); 

    }

}
```

The XML-file is in the layout folder and has the name fragment_1. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f0f0f0" >

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is fragment 1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="60dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import proper R.java file.Not **import android.R**

That will resolve your problem for sure

Comment: Thanks. This was it. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: great helped me out aswell

Answer (score 2):

remove your following import

```
import android.R;
```

and try again with this import

```
import yourpackagename.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Import R file of your application not that of android
Problem is in the following line

```
import android.R;
```